# How to connect the Peltier module to TEC W1209?

Tags: relay, circuit-design, peltier, controller

I am trying to control my Peltier module using the W1209 TEC. I set the P0 to H, so that it should provide voltage to my Peltier module until the temperature reaches the set temp. The LED turns on indicating that the load should be turned on, but when I checked there was no voltage between pins K1 and K0, or between either of them and the GND.

I connected 12 VDC supply to pin +12V and GND. I tried different ways to connect my load. I connected it between pins K0 and K1, I also tried using a jumper cable between pins K1 and +12V with the Peltier module attached to K1 and K0, and I also tried the positive of battery being connected to K1 and +12V, its negative connected to ground, and the Peltier module connected to K0 and GND. None of them worked.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong? The Peltier module works when connected directly to power supply.

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Have you tried operating the controller with no load?

Comment: The correct way to connect it is the last way you mentioned.  +12V goes to both +12V and K1.  Your Peltier is connected to K0 and GND.  When the module calls for cooling it activates that relay next to the connections.  Can you probe for voltage across the relay coils to see if the module is trying to activate the relay?

Comment: I haven't checked the voltage across relays yet but I can try. It will be a good way to check if the w1209 is even working the way it is supposed to. @mike65535 I tried running the controller without load. It doesn't generate any current.

Comment: To be clear: I mean, disconnect the load, and measure what happens on the controller board to the two terminals that used to go to the load.  Make sure the controller is providing the correct voltage - at the right times- across the pair of pins when no load is attached.